# SQLite update trigger changes all rows in the table

Tags: sqlite, triggers

Problem: a simplest possible update trigger writes a new value to all table rows instead of just the row being updated. Here is the table:

**[names]**

```
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
name TEXT
len INTEGER
```

Now I want to create triggers to update 'len' with the length of 'name'. This INSERT trigger seems to be doing the job corectly:

```
CREATE TRIGGER 'namelen' AFTER INSERT ON 'names'
BEGIN
UPDATE 'names' SET len = length(NEW.name) WHERE (id=NEW.id);
END;
```

Problems begin when I add a similar UPDATE trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER 'namelenupd' AFTER UPDATE ON 'names'
BEGIN
UPDATE 'names' SET len = length(NEW.name) WHERE (OLD.id=NEW.id);
END;
```

The update trigger writes the new length to **all rows** of the table, despite the WHERE clause. For example, if I say

```
UPDATE 'names' SET name='foo' where id=1;
```

then the value of 'len' becomes 3 for **all rows** of the table. I've looked at sqlite trigger examples and I can't see my error. What else must I do to make sure the trigger updates the 'len' column **only** in the row(s) that are actually updated?

Comment: did you try **UPDATE 'names' SET len = length(NEW.name) WHERE (id=OLD.id);**

Comment: How did you fix this ?

Answer (score 11):

Both OLD.xxx and NEW.xxx refer to the table row that caused the trigger to run.
The UPDATE statement inside the trigger runs independently; if you want to restrict it to one table row, you have to explicitly do this in its WHERE clause by filtering on *that* statement's table values, i.e., `names.id` or just `id`.

When the original UPDATE statement does not change the `id` column, the old and new `id` values are the same, and the expression `OLD.id=NEW.id` is true for *all* records in the table, as seen by the inner UPDATE statement.

The correct trigger looks like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER "namelenupd"
AFTER UPDATE OF name ON "names"
BEGIN
    UPDATE "names" SET len = length(NEW.name) WHERE id = NEW.id;
END;
```

Comment: If the original UPDATE statement does not change the id, then id = NEW.id is true for all rows right ?

Comment: @Amina No; `id` has a different value for each row, but `NEW.id` is a *single* value during one execution of the trigger.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same issue, here's the syntax from my trigger

You would change "ALTER" to "CREATE" depending on what you already have (or not)

You have `"id"` as your primary key

Your dbo is `"names"`

Obviously, this will set the name value to "foo" (not really what you wanted). The key seems to be the last line, where you set `inner join inserted on names.Id = inserted.Id`.

```
USE [yourDBname]
    ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[yourTrigger]
       ON  [dbo].[names] 
       After INSERT, UPDATE 
    AS 

    BEGIN
        -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
        -- interfering with SELECT statements.
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

    Select id from inserted
        begin
         update [dbo].names
            set [dbo].names.name = 'foo' 
            from dbo.names 
               inner join inserted 
               on names.id = inserted.id
        END
```

Comment: SQLite has no USE or ALTER TRIGGER.

Comment: For a question about SQLite, this answer is not useful *at all*. This is exactly what downvotes are for.

Comment: There's a big difference between the T-SQL (For SQL Server) and SQL syntax used by sqlite.  TSQL (on MSSQL servers) is SQL-92 compliant, but there's a lot of leeway in the specification.  All the various SQL flavors are also SQL-92 compliant, but their features may work differently than expected, or not at all.  Please don't think SQL-92 code is compatible between databases.  That kind of thinking is a dangerous trap.