# SQLite3 update trigger fires on all rows, ignores WHEN and/or WHERE condition(s)

Tags: sqlite

I tried to add an UPDATE trigger to a table in Sqlite3 and the trigger updates ALL rows despite my efforts to limit it to only the rows that actually change. Simple made-up example table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS prices (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    base REAL DEFAULT 100.0,
    discount REAL DEFAULT 0.0,
    actual REAL DEFAULT 0.0
);
INSERT INTO prices(base,discount,actual) VALUES (100,0,100),(200,0,200),(300,0,300);
```

The actual price is supposed to be updated using the following trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER "upd" AFTER UPDATE OF discount ON prices FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (OLD.discount <> NEW.discount)
BEGIN
    UPDATE prices SET actual = base * (1-NEW.discount/100.0)
    WHERE OLD.discount <> NEW.discount;
END;
```

If I change let's say the 2nd row thus:

```
UPDATE prices SET discount = 50 WHERE rowid = 2;
```

then the trigger is fired on **all** rows, not only on the second, and the "actual" fields in all rows will be multiplied by 0.5.

As you can see, the trigger wears a belt and a suspender: both the WHEN clause and the WHERE clause try to ensure that only those rows are affected for which the discount value changed. Tried all 4 combinations by specifying either/or WHEN, WHERE, etc. to no avail. Here is the contents of the table after the `UPDATE`:

```
1|100.0|0.0|50.0
2|200.0|50.0|100.0
3|300.0|0.0|150.0
```

Note that there is a seemingly related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047915/sqlite-update-trigger-changes-all-rows-in-the-table) but there the OP used the following clause: `WHERE (OLD.id=NEW.id)` which is of course `TRUE` for all unchanged rows, so no wonder it did not work as expected. I am afraid the solutions offered there do not apply to my case. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: After CL. -s explanation here is the correct trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER "upd" AFTER UPDATE OF discount ON prices FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE prices SET actual = base * (1-NEW.discount/100.0)
    WHERE id = NEW.id; -- this selects the row that fired the trigger!
END;
```

Comment: You are making *exactly* the same error as moodforaday; I've updated that answer to be more clear.

Comment: Thank you, _now_ it is clear. The original SQLite docs are definitely unclear on this. I come from Postgres where triggers invoke stored procs and the stored proc has access to two records, OLD and NEW, holding the old and new values _of the row that fired the trigger_. Which means Postgres trigger functions do not need an  extra `id = NEW.id` check. Many thanks for the clarification.