# PostgreSQL use trigger to update table

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I wanted to clear the latitude when I modify the address of table CarBay by using a trigger here. But it deletes all latitudes in this table. What can I do to fix this problem?

```
CREATE TABLE CarBay(
       carBayName   VARCHAR(20),
       address      VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL,
       description  VARCHAR(50),  
       latitude     DECIMAL(8,5),
       longitude    DECIMAL(8,5),
       PRIMARY KEY (carBayName)
);

    CREATE FUNCTION changeBayName() RETURNS trigger AS $$
        BEGIN 
            UPDATE CarBay
            SET latitude = NULL
            WHERE OLD.address != NEW.address;
            RETURN NEW;
        END
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

    CREATE TRIGGER changeBay AFTER UPDATE OF address ON CarBay 
                        FOR EACH ROW 
                        EXECUTE PROCEDURE changeBayName();
```

Comment: OMG! You put a semicolon after NULL! The update statement got terminated there, did not go to where clause and ..BOOM! Updated everything, destroyed latitude column with NULL. And I was thinking of rocket science here. But thanks to you, I got a better grip on triggers :-D

Comment: oh, that was a mistake, i deleted that already. but its still this problem.

Comment: Did you try a BEFORE trigger? I had read somewhere AFTER triggers are normally used for logging, and some catch regarding NEW clause in AFTER trigger. Unable to recollect now. So did not post. Give it a try.

Comment: no BEFORE does not work : (

Comment: Borrowing from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047915/sqlite-update-trigger-changes-all-rows-in-the-table  You should mention address=NEW.address ; See CL's answer there, you will get why.

Comment: Resolved? I also see a similar answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you filter `OLD.address != NEW.address` you change all addresses because by definition the old address is updated to a new address (the `AFTER UPDATE OF address` clause in the trigger). Instead, you should only clear the `latitude` (and presumably the `longitude`) where the address in the table is equal to the `NEW` address.

```
CREATE FUNCTION changeBayName() RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN 
    UPDATE CarBay
    SET latitude = NULL, longitude = NULL
    WHERE address = NEW.address;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```